# Current Alternative To .fontcolor() method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was given this task with some existing code to change the string color of each of three selector.value(s) that is output onto an input element to three different colors. The code boils the three selectors into a single output variable. Without destroying the code, I cannot figure out how to select each individual variables prior to condensing them.

If I could use the fontcolor() method, my life would be great but it's 2018 and I can't. Is there any way you can think of to solve this issue?To clarify, I need to alter the colors of the strings that belong to output(red), select1.value(blue) and select2.value(black.

Most of the action for this is happening in the parseOutput() function but I'm just stuck and don't think it's possible without rewriting the entire program.

```
function updateSelector(result){

var options = result.options;

var elementId = "select" + result.element;

var logger = document.getElementById('logger');

var selector = document.getElementById(elementId);

//logger.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(elementId);

selector.innerHTML = options;

selector.disabled = false;

}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateSelector).processOptions(0);

plate();

function resetAll(){

for (var i = 0;i<3;i++){

var selector = document.getElementById('select' + i);

selector.disabled = true;

selector.innerHTML = "";

}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateSelector).processOptions(0);

}

function finalSelection(){

var output = document.getElementById('out');

//output.focus();

output.select();

}

function plate(){

var plate = document.getElementById('plate');

plate.innerHTML = atob('Q3JhZnRlZCBieTogWmFjaGFyeSBTdGFjaG93aWFr');

}

//Adds the location as initial output, followed by divider, application, and issue if select1 is selected

//else statement added so if select0 is [Costco Website Name], to ommit the " - "

function parseOutput(){

var output = "";

if (select1.value.length > 0 && select0.value !== "[Costco Website Name]"){

output = output + ' - ' + select1.value + ' // ' + select2.value;

} else{

output = output + select1.value + ' // ' + select2.value;

}

out.value=output.trim();

}
```

And this is the Div that displays the output:

```
 <div class="wide"><p><input class="wide" type="readonly" id="out" onfocus="this.select();"></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A modern replacement for `fontcolor` would use a `span` and a `style` (or class), e.g.:

```
function modernFontColor(str, color) {
    return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + str + '</span>';
}
```

or

```
function modernFontClass(str, cls) {
    return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + str + '</span>';
}
```

...where the class defines the styling.